# Simple Multi Threading Progress Bar Example

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, progress-bar, invoke

On my project I have the need of notifying the user the progress of certain operations, by the use of a progress bar.
Now, I know there's a ton of threads out there explaining how to do it, but every example I tried seems to not be working as expected...

The most simple example I found of doing what I need was on the Microsoft Support ([here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315577)), but it seems that I get the following error when I run the application:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

This is the code fully organized:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Private trd As Thread

    Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
        MessageBox.Show("This is the main thread")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadTask()
        Dim stp As Integer
        Dim newval As Integer
        Dim rnd As New Random()

        Do
            stp = ProgressBar1.Step * rnd.Next(-1, 2)
            newval = ProgressBar1.Value + stp
            If newval > ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
                newval = ProgressBar1.Maximum
            ElseIf newval < ProgressBar1.Minimum Then
                newval = ProgressBar1.Minimum
            End If

            ProgressBar1.Value = newval

            Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, after a bit of searching and reading on Delegates and the Invoke Method, I added the following lines of code at the beggining of the **ThreadTask** method:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf ThreadTask))
    Return
End If
```

After adding the lines of code above, I was able to run the application. However, I'm not able to use the **btnTest** Button and the button isn't even drawn...

(I still can't post images due to low reputation. Sorry...)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. May anyone help me please?

Comment: The background worker is intended to make this sort of thing easy.  It includes a ReportProgress method and ProgressChanged event for updating something like a progressbar.  Your delegate logic is backwards, you'd use InvokeRequired (or just Invoke) where you talk to the control from the thread

Comment: Running the thread on the load-function already can be an issue.     Create a button to run the thread, then create one that runs the same sub without putting it in a thread. That can show the difference quite well. You can check with "if me.invoerequired = true  " if an invoke is needed.              There are tons of good examples of hyperthreading, one that should be helpful (it was for me )  : http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?682082-Understanding-Multi-Threading-in-VB-Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be invoking the whole method, just the code that is updating the progress bar.

Instead of `ProgressBar1.Value = newval`

You should replace this with `ProgressBar1.BeginInvoke(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = newvalue)`

However it is easier to do this sort of simple update with a `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: Lol! I never thought you could pass a property on the BeginInvoke method...
Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

As said the backgroundworker can do all this for you...

```
Dim bw As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
```

Then you need to start it and do the handlers..

```
bw.runworkerasync



Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Try

            Dim lp As Integer = "0"

            for i = 0 to 100
                lp = lp + 1
                bw.ReportProgress((lp / sz) * 100)
            Next

        End If
    Catch x As System.Exception
        ''do some error handling

    End Try
End Sub
```

ProgressBar1 should be added to the form

```
Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

   'do some reporting 
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        End Sub
```

I've used this before and I've not had the cross thread violation.

Comment: use `WithEvents` rather than adding all the handlers yourself

Comment: Also you need to set the `WorkerReportsProgress = True` property as this is False by default

Comment: @Chris S Hummm... I know you can use Background Worker along with multithread for situations such as this, but I'm not sure if it'll work for my project. The example I gave here, was the starting point and I wish to go from there in order to get my project going.
If all else fails, I guess I'll try the Background Worker.

Comment: Well. It appears that the best approach was actually through the use of a Background Worker.
Everything is working real nice now :)

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5.  Is the VB.Net BackgroundWorker deprecated or obsolete?